# How can I set a file upload function?

Tags: file-upload, upload, sapui5

I am creating an SAPUI5 WebApp with an file upload function. I try this example from SAPUi5 Explored: [sap.m.sample.UploadCollection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.8/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollection/preview)

I try with my trial account in SAP WebIDE to set the upload function ( Upload Collection)

The issue is, not allowing to upload a file in the project folder or local desktop folder.

[image: Upload Collection]

> If I upload a file it appears but i can't open it and I get a 405 HTTP
> error.

Any Ideas, what the problem is?

Comment: Did you implement a backend that stores the file somewhere?

Comment: no, i havn't a backend. Did I need a backend?

Comment: Where do you think the uploaded files are stored?

Comment: of course you need a backend

Answer (score 1):

like you see already in your posts comments, you need a backend for this task. The UploadCollection control is only usable with a backend in the background which receives the transmitted file from the control.

On the page https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection you see

> This control allows you to upload single or multiple files from your devices (desktop, tablet or phone) and attach them to the application
>   while you can replace "application" with "receiving backend"

Indipendent of this may I allowed to ask where do you think the file should be uploaded when not to a backend system? I mean when you choose a file from your local storage it doesn't make any sense to upload it again to your local storage?!